# VS2022 Create New Theme from current settings?

Tags: themes, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to find a way to create an actual *theme* from my existing settings in VS2022. I've installed the Visual Studio Color Theme Designer 2022, but it requires me to choose a theme to use as a "seed" which is unacceptable.  I need something that will actually look at all of the existing settings and extract them into the .pkgdef format that is used by the theme projects I've examined.

Does such a tool exist (if so, *please* help me find it!), or must I spend countless hours poking at each of the hundreds of settings in the "seed" them to get each one to what I want, constantly building my new theme, test loading it, and then importing a previously saved .vssettings file to fix everything that is still wrong with the settings, and repeat until driven into madness?

In reality, I'm trying to do this because it appears to be impossible to find a dark mode theme that **does not** change any of the settings in the text editor window -- so I'm going to try to make a theme that uses *my* preferred text editor colors with a dark mode.  But, help finding the tool I'm looking for would be a huge step in the right direction of resolving this for me.